How to show the "Hide Change" and "Stage Change" in xcode?
I am using Xcode 15 and have two projects, both under Git version control. In one project, when I make changes to the code and click the blue line next to the modified lines, I only see the option to "Discard Change."
However, in the other project, I see three options: "Hide Change," "Stage Change," and "Discard Change."
What could be the reason for this difference, and how can I enable all three options in both projects?
project one:

project two:


@matt the problem is I can't hide, it show old and new code at the same time and messed up everything

Choose View > Hide Code Review.

@matt why did u delete ur old comment?

You have turned on Code Review. Turn it off: Choose View > Hide Code Review.

